# Does std::map::find performance depend on the key size?

Tags: c++, dictionary, find, time-complexity

Say I have the the following `map` definition:

```
std::map<string,Storage>
```

where the **key** is the string representation of a `Storage` class instance.
My question is, even though it stated that [map::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) *complexity
is logarithmic in size*, does the `string` size has any influence on the performance?

The reason I have this `map` is to enable fast access to `Storage` class instance. However, what if the string representation of `Storage` classes is very long? Is there a max string size that if exceeded makes the use of `map` redundant?

#### Notes

My intuition tells me that if *the string representation of `Storage` classes is very long* then comparing the classes themselves using `operator==` would be expensive as well. So no matter how long the string is, I'm better of using `map`

Comment: In `map`, the computation related to keys is **comparison and ordering.** If you have long strings with the same long prefix, that may take some time. However, I highly doubt this would be an actual performance bottleneck. Don't worry about it. Benchmark, measure, only optimize if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the map has to perform a less-than comparison of the keys. This is a lexicographical comparison and is linear WRT the string size.

This does not affect the time complexity of the `find` method, which refers to the number of comparisons required. It affects the constant factor.

Whether that matters or not in your application should be determined empirically.

Answer (score 3):

`std::map` uses lexicographical ordering for the key type. This means that performance of search operations on the map is determined by the shared prefix of keys in the map and the key you are looking for. If you have many keys sharing a very long prefix, and you search for a key with that prefix, performance will dwindle.

For example, this is expensive:

```
aaaaaa <millions of a's> aaaa
aaaaaa <millions of a's> aaab
aaaaaa <millions of a's> aaac
```

This is cheap:

```
aaaaaa <millions of a's> aaaa
baaaaa <millions of a's> aaaa
caaaaa <millions of a's> aaaa
```

Comment: Say your "expensive` example apply to my scenario, should I use `vector` instead of `map` and compare instances using `operator==`? or `map` will always be more efficient?

Comment: @idanshmu I can't say, you should profile. Also consider [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Answer (score 2):

The "complexity" of a map lookup is defined in units of comparisons. So "logarithmic in size" means it will perform `O(log(size()))` key comparisons. For expensive key comparisons, this indeed affects actual performance.

Comment: The asker is interested not in how the performance scales in relation to `size()`, but in relation to the size of the key.

Comment: @nightcracker The way I see it, the OP is asking whether the "complexity" is affected by key size. So I am saying it will perform that many *key comparisons," not necessarily that many "constant time operations."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, comparing two strings(with a long shared prefix) are generally O(n) complexity.

if strings do not share a long prefix, it may take less time.

Generally, longer strings take longer time to compare.

Maybe you should consider unordered_map (hash_table) if key is a string.

Comment: "Generally, longer strings take longer time to compare." I would argue with that. If we assume that the probability of some characters from two strings being the same is `1/card(A)`, where `A` is the alphabet, then simple calculations show that comparing two random strings takes `O(1)` time.

Anyway, the time depends on the distributions of strings.

Comment: @lisyarus lexicographically comparing two strings is O(N). There isn't much that can be done about that.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I'm talking about amortized time of comparing loads of strings.

Comment: @lisyarus Say you make M comparisons of pairs of strings randomly drawn from a normally distributed sample of mean size N. Are you saying that this would take the same time as doing it with a sample of mean size N*100?